# Is a class that creates an instance of another its parent?

Tags: java

If class A creates an instance of class B, then in class B can I run a method from class A? sorry if the question is poorly worded, I don't know how else I could say it.

Comment: give class b an instance of calls a in the constructor.

Comment: Well, try it!! Write a small sample that you'd like to get to work, and report f you're stuck.

Comment: Parent usually implies inheritance. A class can only call methods on references that it has. Inheritance is one way to do it; composition is another.

Comment: If A is *parent* of B, typically that means that B inherits from A.  If, instead, A contains a B, you might call A the *owner* of the B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below code, Class A creates an instance of Class B and you can call Class A's method from Class B's method.

```
class A {
    public void getA() {
         System.out.println("In A");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        b.getB();
    }

}

class B {
    public void getB() {
        System.out.println("In B");
        A a = new A();
        a.getA();
    }

}
```

Output:

In B

In A

Comment: @CharlieLandrigan If my answer helped you, Could you please upvote it or mark it accepted. I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In class B you can call methods of class A only if A's methods are visible to B. It doesn't matter who created an instance of B.

This tutorial might help: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_access_modifiers.htm

So you can call it if the method is one of the following:

- public
- protected (and B is a subclass of A or B is in the same package as A)
- no modifier (and B is in the same package as A)